# How to remove duplicate messages with multiple rss feed sources in spring integration feed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rss, spring-integration

How to remove duplicate messages with multiple rss feed sources in spring integration feed as done by FeedEntryMessageSource with shared MetadataStore.

I have followed this example for https://github.com/okihouse/spring-integration-rss-multiple-urls, for multiple urls, now i want to remove duplicate messages from each source. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look into [Idempotent Receiver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#idempotent-receiver) pattern.

And after splitting all that `List<SyndFeed>` you should check if you haven't processed the entry before. I mean that the next endpoint after `splitter` should be marked for the `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
@Splitter(inputChannel = "splitterChannel")
public MessageHandler splitter() {
    DefaultMessageSplitter defaultMessageSplitter = new DefaultMessageSplitter();
    defaultMessageSplitter.setOutputChannelName("serviceChannel");
    return defaultMessageSplitter;

}

@Bean
public IdempotentReceiverInterceptor idempotentReceiverInterceptor() {
   return new IdempotentReceiverInterceptor(new MetadataStoreSelector(...));
}


@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
@IdempotentReceiver("idempotentReceiverInterceptor")
public void processFeed(SyndFeed feed) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Artem_Bilan thanks for the fast reply. Can you please post an example for the same that you have mentioned, for the example that i have pasted in the question, using java config. Also How to implement the same for multiple instances.

Comment: Added some EDIT into an answer.

Comment: Please, read that Reference Manual about `IdempotentReceiverInterceptor`. The duplication logic is implemented exactly there. You only need to provide a proper key for uniqueness identification and the behavior what to do with duplicates.

Comment: @Artem_Bilan sorry to disturb you but can you please help me with the implementation for metadatastore for multiple urls, to persist lastpubdate for different sources and then use that metadatastore in the IdempotentReceiverInterceptor to filter the messages for each source.

Comment: No, you have to use different `MetadataStore`s for `FeedMessageSoure` and for Idempotent Receiver. Different logic different stores. Yes, that can be the same instance, BTW, but with different key logic you will reach a desired behavior anyway. And no: I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: @Artem_Bilan Thanks for the help. Again sorry, i'm new to spring-integration.

Comment: OK. That' fine. So, just read a Reference Manual and take a look into Sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples. Everything rest yeah... you should figure out yourself :-)